# How to handle search term concatenations in SOLR

Tags: lucene, solr

We are currently replacing our product search from mysql to a SOLR backend. Our customer often search for terms like 'startrek online', 'starwars', 'redsteel' or even 'grandtheftauto'. Is there a method in SOLR to either expand or spellcheck these searches into syllables eg.'star trek online', 'star wars', 'red steel', 'grand theft auto'?

Comment: you can spellcheck via spellcheck.txt file in the conf dir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a synonym file. Take a look into [this documenation site](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters) (solr.SynonymFilterFactory):

```
<fieldtype name="syn" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="syn.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

For the searchquery splitting the WordDelimiterFilterFactory could match partially your needs, but maybe the synomymfilter is easier and better (+ probably faster).

Comment: I was hoping for a more genric solution than the synonym file. But I will give the LetterDelimitedFilterFactory a try.

Comment: you could try to ask this on the mailing list. Maybe there are hacks or patches for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can try modifying your search terms using Levenshtein but also making use of SoundEx / Metaphone to improve matches.

http://web.elctech.com/2008/04/13/advanced-solr-filters-with-phonetics/

http://web.elctech.com/2009/07/06/solr-vs-sphinx-fuzzy-search/